# Create a combination from dynamic loop

Tags: php, loops, recursion

First of all, I created 5 criteria to rate a person. each criteria can be rated in 3 ways, which are low, medium, high. now, i want to create a combination from this 5 criteria. this created 243 combination (from 3^5)

for example :

**first combination :**

criteria 1 : low,
criteria 2 : low,
criteria 3 : low,
criteria 4 : low,
criteria 5 : low

**second combination :**

criteria 1 : low,
criteria 2 : low,
criteria 3 : low,
criteria 4 : low,
criteria 5 : high

...

**243rd combination**

criteria 1 : high,
criteria 2 : high,
criteria 3 : high,
criteria 4 : high,
criteria 5 : high

[image: combination picture]

the code that I create it works fine, but when I try to make it dynamic so the number of criteria can be modified by using recursion (the criteria is taken from the database), it doesn't work well. here is my static code (only work for 5 criteria) :

```
$criteria1 = array('low'=>0,'medium'=>1,'high'=>2);
$criteria2 = array('low'=>0,'medium'=>1,'high'=>2);
$criteria3 = array('low'=>0,'medium'=>1,'high'=>2);
$criteria4 = array('low'=>0,'medium'=>1,'high'=>2);
$criteria5 = array('low'=>0,'medium'=>1,'high'=>2);
$level = array('low'=>0,'medium'=>1,'high'=>2);//buat give integer value to low, high, medium

foreach($criteria1 as $key1=>$a){
    foreach($criteria2 as $key2=>$b){
        foreach($criteria3 as $key3=>$c){
            foreach($criteria4 as $key4=>$d){
                foreach($criteria5 as $key5=>$e){
                    $warna[] = array('criteria1'=>$key1,'criteria2'=>$key2,'criteria3'=>$key3,'criteria4'=>$key4,'criteria5'=>$key5);//to get 5 criteria combination per row

                    if( $level[$key1] >= $level['medium'] &&  $level[$key2] == $level['medium'] &&  $level[$key3] >=  $level['medium'] &&  $level[$key4] >=  $level['medium'] && $level[$key5] ==  $level['medium']){
                        $rule[] = "DPM1";
                    } else if(( $level[$key1] >= $level['medium'] &&  $level[$key2] >  $level['medium'] &&  $level[$key3] >=  $level['medium'] &&  $level[$key4] >=  $level['medium'] && $level[$key5] ==  $level['medium'])||
                        ($level[$key1] >= $level['medium'] &&  $level[$key2] ==  $level['medium'] &&  $level[$key3] >=  $level['medium'] &&  $level[$key4] >=  $level['medium'] && $level[$key5] >  $level['medium']))
                    {
                        $rule[] = "DPM2";

                    }
                    else if($level[$key1] >= $level['medium'] &&  $level[$key2] >  $level['medium'] &&  $level[$key3] >=  $level['medium'] &&  $level[$key4] >=  $level['medium'] && $level[$key5] > $level['medium']){
                        $rule[] = "DTM";
                    }
                    else{
                        $rule[] = "TD";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

here is my dynamic code, but it still doesn't work

```
//in main
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM kriteria") or die(mysql_error()); 
$totalcriteria = mysql_num_rows($res);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
    $full[] = $row['nama'];//get the criteria name from database and fill in full
}

createCombination($totalcriteria,$full);
/* ...... */


function createCombination($index,$full){
    if($index > 0){
        $index = $index-1;

        $thiskriteria = $full[$index]; 
        $thiskriteria = array("rendah"=>0,"sedang"=>1,"tinggi"=>2);
        foreach($thiskriteria as $key=>$a){
            createCombination($index,$full);
        }
    } else{//create the combination
        $warna[] = array('criteria1'=>$key1,'criteria2'=>$key2,'criteria3'=>$key3,'criteria4'=>$key4,'criteria5'=>$key5);

        if( $tingkat[$key1] >= $tingkat['sedang'] &&  $tingkat[$key2] == $tingkat['sedang'] &&  $tingkat[$key3] >=  $tingkat['sedang'] &&  $tingkat[$key4] >=  $tingkat['sedang'] && $tingkat[$key5] ==  $tingkat['sedang']){
            $rule[] = "DPM1";//rule buat nampung list terima ato kaga
        } else if(( $tingkat[$key1] >= $tingkat['sedang'] &&  $tingkat[$key2] >  $tingkat['sedang'] &&  $tingkat[$key3] >=  $tingkat['sedang'] &&  $tingkat[$key4] >=  $tingkat['sedang'] && $tingkat[$key5] ==  $tingkat['sedang'])||
            ($tingkat[$key1] >= $tingkat['sedang'] &&  $tingkat[$key2] ==  $tingkat['sedang'] &&  $tingkat[$key3] >=  $tingkat['sedang'] &&  $tingkat[$key4] >=  $tingkat['sedang'] && $tingkat[$key5] >  $tingkat['sedang']))
        {
            $rule[] = "DPM2";

        }
        else if($tingkat[$key1] >= $tingkat['sedang'] &&  $tingkat[$key2] >  $tingkat['sedang'] &&  $tingkat[$key3] >=  $tingkat['sedang'] &&  $tingkat[$key4] >=  $tingkat['sedang'] && $tingkat[$key5] > $tingkat['sedang']){
            $rule[] = "DTM";
        }
        else{
            $rule[] = "TD";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve. Can you clarify?

Comment: Are you trying to create an array which contains all 243 (or dynamic number of) criteria or what?

Comment: yes,i'm trying to create a dynamic number of criteria, so the code can also work for 4,6 or 7 criteria. maybe the picture can help you understand

Comment: How you do dynamic determine the rule name (DPM1, DPM2, DTM, TD)?

Comment: Oops, sorry that I'm sleepy and made a typo. I mean how do you dynamically determine the rule name when there're dynamic number of criteria?

Comment: the minimum criteria is 5 (can be 6,7,etc). the 6th,7th,.. criteria stay the same rule as the first criteria in if-else statement